# confusing code, compiles fine. How this code works?

Tags: java, types

Following code compiles and gives `1` as output, its a bit confusing for me. I tried `javap` for this but from there also I couldn't figure out. I have checked for similar posts but couldn't find out similar question here.

Take look at the code:

```
int i = (byte) + (char) - (int) + (long) - 1;
System.out.println(i);
```

here is bytecode for it

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

How the types are working here? is it dependent of size of datatype? How the code is working?

Comment: @Aquillo I find it really interesting and tried hard to figure out, but couldn't. :)

Comment: It is the same as `int i = +-+-1`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is just a sequence of unary + and - operations mixed with type casts.

You start with -1, cast it to a long, the unary plus does nothing, cast it to an int, unary minus (value is now +1), cast to char, unary +, cast to byte.

Answer (score 6):

You can read as

```
int i = + - + - 1;
System.out.println(i);
```

or if you prefer

```
int i = - - 1;
System.out.println(i);
```

or if you prefer

```
int i = -1 * - 1;
System.out.println(i);
```

the other casts have no effect.

Comment: it is just sequence of operations followed with typecasts. :)